# Logging config fails to the load the value-formatter() when the application has multiple calls

Tags: python, python-logging

I am using bottle wsgi framework to create web service. I configured the logger in app.py (shown in the app.py) which receives the application call and passes input parameters to backend.py using the method get_output(). I am using the backend.py to process the request of the application. In the backend file the logger config is set using self.logger for every instance of processor (shown in the backend.py file)

**app.py**

```
from bottle import Bottle
import logging.handlers
from backend import Processor

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Logging handler for files
file_handler = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler("log.log", when="midnight", interval=1,
                                                         backupCount=10000)
file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# Logging handler for console
console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
console_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Formatter's for logging
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
console_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

# Add handlers to the logger
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
logger.addHandler(console_handler)


class App:

    def __init__(self, host, port, server):
        logger.info("Initializing the app")
        self.processor = Processor()
        self._app = Bottle()
        self._host = host
        self._port = port
        self._server = server

    def _route(self):
        self._app.route('/hello/<attribute>/<number>', method="POST", callback=self.get_output)

    def start(self):
        self._app.run(server=self._server, host=self._host, port=self._port)  ## Starts the service
        logger.info("Web service started.")

    def get_output(self, attribute, number):
        logger.info("Got the input attribute {}".format(attribute))
        result = self.processor.compute(attribute, number)
        return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = App(server='waitress', host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
    server.start()
```

**backend.py**

```
 import logging


class Processor:

    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)  # Setting the logging config
        self.attribute = None  ############ Setting this variable to None for the instance

    def set_attributes(self, input_attribute):
        self.attribute = input_attribute  ############### Setter to set the attribute

    def compute(self, attribute, number):
        self.set_attributes(attribute)
        self.logger.info("Completed processing the attribute {}".format(self.attribute))
        res = number + 5
        return res
```

**Issue is logger picks previous request argument stored in the shared memory (It picks Blue for Green...etc) whenever there are multiple calls to this app.py file.**

I recreated the logging statements, as shown below

```
2019-12-23 15:15:46,992 yoshi INFO Web service started.
Bottle v0.13-dev server starting up (using WaitressServer())...
Listening on http://0.0.0.0:8090/
Hit Ctrl-C to quit.

Serving on http://0.0.0.0:8090

line1: 2019-12-23 15:15:47,327 app.py INFO Got the input attribute Green
line2: 2019-12-23 15:15:47,327 app.py INFO Got the input attribute Blue
line3: 2019-12-23 15:15:47,327 backend.py INFO Completed processing the attribute Green
line4: 2019-12-23 15:15:47,327 app.py INFO Got the input attribute Black
line5: 2019-12-23 15:15:47,327 backend.py INFO Completed processing the attribute Green <<<-----This needs to be Blue, but it is Green again (Is it because self.attribute = None)
line6: 2019-12-23 15:15:47,327 backend.py INFO Completed processing the attribute Black
line7: 2019-12-23 15:15:47,327 backend.py INFO Completed processing the attribute None <<<-----This needs to be Violet, but it is None again (Is it because self.attribute = None)
line8: 2019-12-23 15:15:47,327 app.py INFO Got the input attribute Violet
```

All together I made 4 calls to the above application in parallel with attributes Green, Blue, Black, Violet

Question:

What is the reason my logger fails in line5 and line7? Is the right way to use a setter method to set the input parameter to whole object? (IF not, How to set the input attribute to a whole new module)

Is it because of shared memory used by self.attribute?? How to solve this??

Looking for an answer to create a logging config which can be used in all the modules of my application. where I need to use the request arguments in the log message and the logger config don't get failed by multiple input calls to the application

Comment: Stupid question: is it a typo in pasted code, or is your constructor in Processor really named wrongly (`__init`)?

Comment: Typo @avysk, Edited

Comment: `result = self.processor(attribute, number)` is a typo as well?

Comment: `set_attributes` never called or am I blind? I don't think you have a working example here.

Comment: My Bad, I overlooked, I have edited. @avysk

Comment: Okay. Now you need to explain better what you are trying to achieve. Your `compute` method receives attribute, and, instead of using it directly, attaches it to `self` and then uses `self.attribute` (yes, that's where the race condition is, because you have only one instance of `Processor`). But why do you want this control flow?

Comment: Assuming I need to use attribute in a third file backend_extended.py in a logging statement, where I have getter() to receive the attribute.  But i don't actually pass attribute to any method in backend_extended.py.

Comment: I'm afraid you need to provide a clearer example to get a reasonable answer. I do not understand what exactly you are trying to achieve, and the results you get are obvious -- you have one instance of `Processor` which you modify in parallel -- of course, you get race conditions. Let me try one more time: do I understand correctly that handling request requires processing some attribute from that request in multiple places, and you do not want to pass it around manually?

Comment: Sorry for unclear example. Yes what you understood is correct. I am trying to process the request for multiple calls, but I am not passing the attribute manually to all the methods as parameter (because all the methods don't use or modify attribute,  it is only used in the log statements within that method).  I thinking of making it global variable to use it in log statements in all the modules of the application

Comment: Can you explain any other control flow, Where I can avoid race condition, and use the attribute in all instances (where I have number of methods in which I don't pass the attribute manually)

Comment: I'll try to post some code in an answer section. See if it does what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may want to use thread-local storage to keep your attribute in. Some modification of your code:

`app.py`:

```
import logging.handlers
import threading

from bottle import Bottle

from backend import Processor
from storage import storage

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Logging handler for files
file_handler = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler("log.log", when="midnight", interval=1,
                                                         backupCount=10000)
file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# Logging handler for console
console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
console_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Formatter's for logging
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
console_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

# Add handlers to the logger
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
logger.addHandler(console_handler)


class App:

    def __init__(self, host, port, server):
        logger.info("Initializing the app")
        self.processor = Processor()
        self._app = Bottle()
        self._host = host
        self._port = port
        self._server = server
        self._app.route('/hello/<attribute>/<number>', method="POST", callback=self.get_output)

    def start(self):
        self._app.run(server=self._server, host=self._host, port=self._port)  ## Starts the service
        logger.info("Web service started.")

    def get_output(self, attribute, number):
        logger.info("Got the input attribute %s", attribute)
        local_storage = storage()
        local_storage.attribute = attribute
        self.processor.compute()
        return f"done for {attribute}"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = App(server='waitress', host='0.0.0.0', port=8081)
    server.start()
```

`backend.py`:

```
import logging
import threading

from more_backend import do_work
from storage import storage


class Processor:

    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)  # Setting the logging config

    def compute(self):
        local_storage = storage()
        do_work()
        self.logger.info("Completed processing the attribute %s", local_storage.attribute)
```

`more_backend.py`:

```
import logging
import threading
import time
import random

from storage import storage

def do_work():
    local_storage = storage()
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.info("Doing work with attribute %s", local_storage.attribute)
    time.sleep(random.random())
```

`storage.py`:

```
from functools import lru_cache
import threading

@lru_cache()
def storage():
    return threading.local()
```

I *think* it will do what you want: `attribute` from every request will be available to all functions involved in the processing of that request, without passing it manually, and without race conditions between threads.